# read multiline file at server side and send lines to browser via ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, string, file

I'm trying to send multilines file (like log-file) from server side to browser (like report). When server responses only one line I have no problem, but when it responses several lines command eval(`function("str")`) calls error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
The file is like this:

10:00:00 - Start program
10:00:10 - Start execution
10:00:11 - Start blablalbla
10:00:14 - Start blablalbla2
10:00:15 - Stop all blablalbla

So I make a loop and cumulate all strings

```
$strOut .= $content[$i];
```

I even added

```
. '\n';
```

but no result. In debugger I see response string in php and in javascript, but when I call eval(request.responseText) I get an error above. 

This is a string which it responses:

```
"myFunction('10:00:00 - Start program10:00:10 - Start execution10:00:11 - Start blablalbla10:00:14 - Start blablalbla210:00:15 - Stop all blablalbla')"
```

If I added **'\n'** after each loop I got this one:

```
"myFunction('10:00:00 - Start program\n10:00:10 - Start execution\n10:00:11 - Start blablalbla\n10:00:14 - Start blablalbla2\n10:00:15 - Stop all blablalbla')"
```

and then in code just `split("\n")`, but it call an error before.

EDIT: My temporary answer is to create separate function to avoid eval. Now it works, but not as I wanted, but works.

Comment: have you tried nl2br ?

Comment: Why you call `eval` on response? Is response JSON?

Comment: what do you want to do in the end ? print the log to browser in separate lines ?

Comment: @Syed Qarib - just tried but no result

Comment: yes I want to print them in textarea

Comment: and call another post (like long-polling)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use \n as a new line separator you need to use double quotes to be interpreted as new line - "\n".

Comment: Ooo OK if you need to apply new line in eval try '\\n' (with two backslash and single quotes in the PHP part)

Comment: I tried a lot of variants before asking here, but it didn't work

Comment: My test with this code works well:
<textarea id="tmp"></textarea>
<script>
eval('document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML = "test\\ntest"');</script>

Comment: I think your code works well, because you added it in textArea rigth now. In my situation I call function with params (like str and status). When I used "\n" or '\r\n' I saw in firebug multiline variable, then I tried to use '\n' and split it in js, but it stoped before in line with eval(funct(str, status)); I have even tried to call without new line - just single string, but and here I got error. I don't know why. May be it is difficult for eval. And I have to send to eval more simple string. But when I copy function without eval it worked.